# Parsing "the rest" of an aeson object

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, monads, aeson

for some reason I can't wrap my head around arbitrarilly successful parses in Aeson, without making the whole system bork and cause a space leak.

Here's my issue:

```
newtype Foo = Foo
  { getFoo :: [(String, Maybe String)]
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance ToJSON Foo where
  toJSON (Foo xs) = object $
    map (\(k,mv) -> T.pack k .= mv) xs
```

so far, encoding a `Foo` is fine and dandy. But, I want to make a parser that *rejects* a couple of keys, if they exist. Right now, I have a pseudo-rejection going on, and that's why I think I'm getting a bad outcome:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap as HM

-- the "duck-tape and chewing gum" approach
instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object o) = Foo <$> parseJSON (Object theRest)
    where
      theRest = foldr HM.delete o [ "foo"
                                  , "bar"
                                  ]
  parseJSON _ = empty
```

This version is what caused me to think that manipulating the internal object was incorrect, because the parser may be getting "more" data in the HashMap, outside of the parser (because of the lazy bytestring being fed into it), but I am clearly not sure about this. So, I tried a different approach:

```
instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    (Foo . filter (\(k,_) -> k `elem` toIgnore)) <$>
      parseJSON (Object o)
    where
      toIgnore = ["foo", "bar"]
  parseJSON _ = empty
```

But this *also* seems to cause a deadlock / space leak (not sure exactly what to diagnose this halting of execution). What would be the advised way to accept everything *except* a few keys of the object? I need to pattern-match on the `(Object o)` structure because I'm manually looking up `o .: "foo"` and `o .: "bar"` in a different component for my data type. Ideally, I would like to just *remove* those keys from the content and continue parsing, because I **already accounted for them** (hence - "the rest").

Is there any hope?

Comment: What is your test code that demonstrates the space leak?

Comment: It might be a lot to compile, but it's from [this repository](https://github.com/athanclark/contact-logger/blob/4250c8f36452934b96044918e5f5321237f45883/src/Application/Api.hs#L215) - if you `:set -XOverloadedStrings` and `import Application.Api` in ghci, and run [this attempt to parse](http://lpaste.net/145756), your computer will bloat.

__Edit__: This assumes you are running GHC >= 7.10

Comment: Another edit: [a more precise attempt to parse](http://lpaste.net/145756)

Comment: I actually had some incorrect logic - it should be `notElem`, not `elem`. However, [this commit](https://github.com/athanclark/contact-logger/blob/805c636da1cbc663fbd4ff74c7975755d36134e8/src/Application/Api.hs#L215) and [this input](http://lpaste.net/145756) (after `:set -XOverloadedStrings`) is still causing the leak.

An interesting attempt I made was to use the `Parser` monad to first get `optional'`'s results _first_, but this caused the entire decode to fail.

Comment: [Here's yet another approach](https://github.com/athanclark/contact-logger/blob/1a5b91744ed6760c76c93f5c4be49b70f9668ff1/src/Application/Api.hs#L215), just to get shot down by the same issue :\

Comment: I also just noticed that _all_ these implementations also fail to parse [this input as well](http://lpaste.net/145758) - a basic example of retrieving the "rest" of the key/values.

So, the parser fails to use `many` with `(<|>)`, and fails to catch the rest.

Comment: Could you please try to prepare a minimalistic example that demonstrates the issue? A self-contained piece of code, a single Haskell file, that can be posted in the question? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your PartialAppContact example here is a more mundane approach which seems to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, QuasiQuotes #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict  as HM
import Control.Monad
import Text.Heredoc

type RequiredField = String
type OptionalField = String

data PartialAppContact = PartialAppContact
  { partialAppContactRequired :: [(RequiredField, String)]
  , partialAppContactOptional :: [(OptionalField, Maybe String)]
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance FromJSON PartialAppContact where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    let required = [ "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phoneNumber" ]
    reqPairs <- forM required $ \k -> do
      v <- o .: k
      s <- parseJSON v
      return (T.unpack k, s)
    nonReqPairs <- forM [ (k,v) | (k,v) <- HM.toList o, k `notElem` required ] $ \(k,v) -> do
      s <- parseJSON v
      return (T.unpack k, s)
    return $ PartialAppContact reqPairs nonReqPairs

test1 = Data.Aeson.eitherDecode "{\"firstName\":\"Athan'\"}" :: Either String PartialAppContact

input = [str|
| { "firstName": "a first name"
| , "lastName": "a last name"
| , "email": "asasd@asd.com"
| , "phoneNumber": "123-123-123"
| , "another field": "blah blah" }
|]

test2 = Data.Aeson.eitherDecode "{\"firstName\":\"Athan'\" }" :: Either String PartialAppContact

test3 = Data.Aeson.eitherDecode input :: Either String PartialAppContact
```

**Update**

Based on your comments, consider this idea for writing the instance:

```
import Data.List (partition)

instance FromJSON PartialAppContact where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    let required = [ "firstName", "lastName", "email", "phoneNumber" ]
    let (group1, group2) = partition (\(k,_) -> k `elem` required) (HM.toList o)
    reqFields   <- forM group1 $ \(k,v) -> do s <- parseJSON v; return (T.unpack k, s)
    otherFields <- forM group2 (\(k,v) -> (T.unpack k,) <$> parseJSON v)
    return $ PartialAppContact reqFields otherFields
```

Comment: This is actually an incorrect implementation - although the variable name usage was misleading, all of the `"firstName"` etc. fields are _optional_. I have made a working solution [here (finally)](https://github.com/athanclark/contact-logger/blob/e8f293000f64cfc8964a88367dd162695dbbb163/src/Application/Api.hs#L208) - I needed to use `(.:?)` to get the optional _known_ fields, then manually decompose the "rest" structure, and reparse the `Maybe String` sub-fields with a `mapM`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working implementation requires the use of `(.:?)`, to correctly implement *optional, known* fields. From there, you can freely decompose the HashMap and re-`parseJSON` it's subfields:

```
instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
    mfoo <- o .:? "foo"
    mbar <- o .:? "bar"
    let foundFields = catMaybes [mfoo, mbar]
    rest <- mapM (\(k,v) -> (T.unpack k,) <$> parseJSON v) 
              (toList theRest)
    return $ Foo rest -- assuming you're done with `foundFields`
    where
      theRest = foldr HM.delete o ["foo", "bar"]
```

To see the final implementation of the issue discussed in the comments, [see this commit](https://github.com/athanclark/contact-logger/blob/e8f293000f64cfc8964a88367dd162695dbbb163/src/Application/Api.hs#L208).